# Return multiple variables in merge method

Tags: java, sorting, recursion

I have written a method to merge sort an array of values. Method works perfectly but I am trying to show the number of comparisons and exchanges that have taken place. My first thought was to create static variables (int comparisons, int exchanges) and pass them into the method. however  am running into problems returning them from the helper method. Is it possible to return an int[] and two ints in the same method? If not, how can I determine the number of comparisons and exchanges that have taken place?

Here are my mergeSort and merge methods:

```
    public static int[] mergeSort(int[] A, int comps, int exchs) {
    // Array has only 1 element
    if( A.length <= 1 ) {
        return A;
    }
    int midPoint = A.length / 2;
    // Initialize left and right arrays.
    int[] left = new int[midPoint];
    int[] right = new int[A.length - midPoint];
    System.arraycopy(A, 0, left, 0, midPoint);
    System.arraycopy(A, midPoint, right, 0, A.length - midPoint);
    //recursively sort left and right arrays
    left = mergeSort(left, comps, exchs);
    right = mergeSort(right, comps, exchs);
    System.out.println("Comparisons" + comps);
    System.out.println("Exchanges" + exchs);
    return merge(left, right, comps, exchs);

} 
private static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right, int comps, int exchs){
    // Initialize the result array.
    int[] res = new int[left.length + right.length];
    // Initialize the array indexes.
    int leftIndex = 0; 
    int rightIndex = 0;
    int resIndex = 0; 
    // compare each element and merge results
    while(leftIndex < left.length && rightIndex < right.length){
        if(left[leftIndex] > right[rightIndex]){
            res[resIndex] = right[rightIndex];
            exchs++;
            rightIndex++;
        } else {
            res[resIndex] = left[leftIndex];
            exchs++;
            leftIndex++; 
        }
        comps++;
        resIndex++;
    }
    comps++;
    // Append remainder of left array into the result array.
    while(leftIndex < left.length){
        res[resIndex] = left[leftIndex];
        exchs++;
        leftIndex++;
        resIndex++;
    }
    comps++;
    // Append whatever is left from the right array into the result array.
    while(rightIndex < right.length) {
        res[resIndex] = right[rightIndex];
        exchs++;
        rightIndex++; 
        resIndex++;
    }
    comps++;
    return res; // want to return comparisons and exchanges to mergeSort method
}
```

Comment: you can modify you variable inputs (exchanges, res) and then consult them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object that does the sorting for you. Then it could store the `comps` and `exchs` and you can just access them with a getter method...

```
public class MergeSorter {
  private int comps = 0;
  private int exchs = 0;

  public int[] mergeSort(int[] A) {
    comps = 0;
    exchs = 0;
    // your code
  }
  private int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
    // your code
  }

  public int getLastComps() { return comps; }
  public int getLastExchs() { return exchs; }
}
```

Comment: Thats very similar to what i was thinking. My sorting methods are all contained within a "Sorter" class so this is very handy to implement. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to return an int[] and two ints in the same method?

Not directly. However, you could create a class that would encapsulate everything you need to return from the method, and return an instance of that class.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class with multiple merge methods, I would create two static class variables. When a method is called, both comparisons and exchanges would be set to 0. As the code progresses, these two values will be updated. You will therefore always know after one of the methods has been called, both variables display the correct value. For example,

```
private static int comparisons;
private static int exchanges;

public static int[] mergeSort(int[] A, int comps, int exchs) {
    comparisons = 0;
    exchanges = 0;
    if( A.length <= 1 ) {
        return A;
    }
    int midPoint = A.length / 2;
    int[] left = new int[midPoint];
    int[] right = new int[A.length - midPoint];
    System.arraycopy(A, 0, left, 0, midPoint);
    System.arraycopy(A, midPoint, right, 0, A.length - midPoint);
    //recursively sort left and right arrays
    left = mergeSort(left, comps, exchs);
    right = mergeSort(right, comps, exchs);
    comparisons = comps;
    exchanges = exchs;
    return merge(left, right, comps, exchs);
}
```

You can now access these static variables after the method has been called, and will be refreshed whenever the method is called again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap those values together. Because you cannot return multiple values at a time from a method. So place all of them an object and return that object.

Example:

```
class WrapperClass {
 int[] array;
 int valueOne;
 int valueTwo;
 // Setters and Getters to these members.
}
```

Sample Method.

```
public WrapperClass method() {
  // Set your values to the object;
  WrapperClass wrapObj = new WrapperClass();
  // set array and the two values to this object.
  // return the object.
  return wrapObj;
}
```